# First-chance exception at 0x7548812f (KernelBase.dll) in videoread.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002cf898

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm using opencv 2.4.10 with visual studio 2010 in Windows 7 32bit OS...

As I'm new to this area, first I tried with displaying image... It works well... But when I'm displaying video, I got this exception... And the code is provided below... Thank you...

```
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace cv;
  int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
string filename = "C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/Wildlife.wmv";
VideoCapture capture(filename);
Mat frame;
if( !capture.isOpened() )
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";
namedWindow( "w", 1);
for( ; ; )
{
    capture >> frame;
    imshow("w", frame);
    waitKey(20); 
}
waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: it may be as simple as: if the movie is over, the capture returns empty frames. (please *always* check `frame.empty()`)

Comment: Thankyou.. even I used that, still having the same exception... for( ; ; ) { capture >> frame; imshow("w", frame); waitKey(33); if ( frame.empty() ) break; } Is this correct?

Comment: Got it now... for( ; ; )
{
    capture >> frame;
 if ( frame.empty() )
       break;
 imshow("w", frame);
    waitKey(33); 
} Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works...

```
   for( ; ; )
    { 
    capture >> frame; 
    if ( frame.empty() ) 
    break; 
    imshow("w", frame); 
    waitKey(33); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `try { ... } catch(cv:Exception const& e){}` clause, to see `e.what()` for the problem.